# Getting UTC time giving me NaN

Tags: javascript

Why am I getting NaN with the following code?

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var utcTime = Date.UTC(currentTime);
console.log(utcTime);
```

Basically, I want to get a date/time value in UTC. What's the best way to get that?

Comment: Date.UTC constructor is `Date.UTC(year, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, millisecond]]]]])` - it doesn't ever take a single argument in the constructor - [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

Comment: perhaps you need `.toUTCString()` to get the UTC date string

Comment: So, I have to go Date.UTC(currentTime.getYear(), currentTime.getMonth(), ...?

Comment: no - Date's a stored as the number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970 0:00:00 UTC ... you don't need to do any gymnastics to get the UTC time - that's how dates are stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log(new Date().toUTCString());
```

Dates already use UTC time internally. They store the number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970 0:00:00 UTC. So, whether you want to show the local time or the UTC time only becomes relevant when wanting to show the value to a user.

---

When sending DateTime values to a ASP.net API, there are two cases:

Newer ASP.net versions use JSON.net for JSON Serializing. They understand the ISO 8601 format. So, use

```
var value = new Date().toISOString();
```

Older ASP.net versions use a Microsoft specific format that you can generate like this:

```
function makeMSDateFormat(date)
{
    return "\/Date(" + date.getTime() + ")\/";
}

var value = makeMSDateFormat(new Date());
```

[Some Background information](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm)

Comment: All I'm trying to do is send a UTC Date and Time value to my API. When I do new Date(), looks like it's getting the user's current date/time. I just want to make sure that the value I send to my API function is a UTC Date/Time.

Comment: This is an ASP.NET API so there's a DateTime data type. The API will automatically convert it to DateTime if the value I send makes sense to it. For example, if I send "hamburger" it won't work but I can try to see if my API will convert new Date().toUTCString() to DateTime. There's a good chance, it may.

Comment: @Sam When using ASP.net, it depends how old your project is. When it is not too old, you should use `new Date().toISOString()`. This is the default format for newer asp.net projects that use JSON.net for Json Serializing.

Comment: Looks like both are working but I think, as you suggested, toISOString() seems much cleaner. Thank you very much. I really appreaciate all your help!